# Scala How do you sort a map that has a String, with numbers in it

Tags: scala, maps

I am trying to sort a mutable.Map[String, String] by getting the string and sorting with the numbers inside the string.
Input:

```
"Liz", "Game: 2"
"Philip", "Game: 5"
"John", "Game: 0 | Score: 9"
"Kevin", "Game: None"
```

Output to something like this

```
"John", "Game: 5 | Score: 9"
"Liz", "Game: 2"
"Philip", "Game: 0"
"Kevin", "Game: None"
```

I have tried this https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-sort-map-in-scala-key-value-sortby-sortwith/
but it doesn't does what I want it to sort
Excuse my bad grammar

Comment: Map are unordered collections, why do you even care about the order?

Comment: @zolmukekni, could you verify if my answer solves your problem ?

Comment: Sorry but I forgot to specify some things in the input and output so it will be different from the answer you gave me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Scala standard library knows how to sort tuples of the same type profile as long as all the internal elements can be sorted.

It also knows how to sort Options as long as the option element can be sorted.

`Float` values can be sorted.

So you can sort your `String` by internal `Int` or `Float` values that might, or might not, be there by stuffing them in a tuple of `Option[Float]` elements.

```
import scala.util.Try

val games =
  scala.collection.mutable.Map("Liz"  -> "Game: 2"
                              ,"John" -> "Game: 0 | Score: 9"
                              ,"Philip" -> "Game: 5"
                              ,"Kevin"  -> "Game: None")
games.put("Jo", "Game: 11 | Score 0")

val numRE = "\\d*\\.?\\d+".r

games.toList.sortBy { case (_, str) =>
  val ns = numRE.findAllIn(str)
                .flatMap(n => Try(n.toFloat).toOption)
                .toVector
  (ns.lift(0), ns.lift(1))
}.reverse
//res1: List[(String, String)] = List((Jo,Game: 11 | Score 0)
//                                  , (Philip,Game: 5)
//                                  , (Liz,Game: 2)
//                                  , (John,Game: 0 | Score: 9)
//                                  , (Kevin,Game: None))
```

Comment: I use a mutable map to .put data and try to sort from there, it doesn't sort nor when I convert it to a immutable map.  It only works if, like the value games, is already in the Map.

Comment: Done it with gradle  2.11:101

Comment: The posted code was tested on Scala 2.12.7 and Scala 2.13.1. It delivers the commented results. I recommend that you paste it into your environment to prove it for yourself before you try to incorporate it into an existing code base.

Comment: I tried you code and printed it, games.foreach{i=> print(i)}: and here the results
(Kevin,Game: None)(Philip,Game: 5)(Jo,Game: 11 | Score 0)(John,Game: 0 | Score: 9)(Liz,Game: 2) Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Ahh I am dumb, need to assign a value.

Comment: If I were to sort numbers like 6.0 or 0.4 (Doubles) how would I sort it?

Comment: Do it will sort my map of data if the numbers are doubles?

Comment: First you have to recognize and capture floating point patterns when parsing the `String`. I've updated the code for `Float` values and removed the need for `Try` (Scala 2.13.x).

Comment: Why does it say that flatMap is overloaded?  And when I tried your code, it gives three errors.

Comment: If you aren't running Scala 2.13.x (as I explicitly specified in the previous comment) then return to the `Try` code of the earlier posted code.

Comment: I am using scala 2.13.1 and it give these errors : error: value toFloatOption is not a member of String and error: diverging implicit expansion for type scala.math.Ordering[(Option[Nothing], Option[Nothing])]
starting with method Tuple9 in object Ordering

Comment: The try method works fine but I don't know why the other method doesn't work.

Comment: Neither do I. The code was tested on 2.13.1. I get those same errors when trying to run it on 2.12.7.

Comment: I have another problem, if the message is something like "Kevin"  -> "None/Out" it doesn't work.  sorry for my bothersome but I don't know regex.

Comment: OK, I realize now that I was over-thinking the pattern matching requirements. Final fix.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the number from you string and convert it to `Integer`, for example:

```
val map: Map[String, String] = Map(("Liz", "Game: 11"), ("Philip", "Game: 5"))
val order: ((String, String)) => Integer = { case (_ , p2) => p2.stripPrefix("Game: ").toInt }
map.toSeq
  .sortWith(order(_) > order(_))
  .toList
```

Comment: I forgot to add this but if the map also have different data, such as "Kevin","Score: 7", or "Mike","Score: 9 Wins:2" how would it work then?

Comment: @zolmukekni then you will need to strip needed number somehow. You can try using regular expression for this.

Answer (score 0):

Sample Data:

```
scala> tmp
res19: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,String] = Map(Philip -> Game: 0, John -> Game: 5, Liz -> Game: 2)
```

Create a case class:

```
case class someclass(name:String,score:Int,keyword:String)
```

Put the data into a `List[someClass]`:

```
val listOfScores = tmp.map(each => { 
  val name = each._1
  val keyword = each._2.split(":")(0)
  val score = each._2.split(":")(1).stripPrefix(" ").toInt
  someclass(name,score,keyword)
})
```

Finally sort and get the final list:

```
scala> listOfScores.toList.sortBy(_.score).reverse
res31: List[someclass] = List(someclass(A1,9,Goals), someclass(a2,5,Game), someclass(Liz,2,Game), someclass(John,0,Score), someclass(Philip,0,Game))
```