# Scala How do I add comma to numbers in a string that is in a list?

Tags: scala

I have managed to create the code to get the numbers and format them but I do not know how to join everything back together.  The problem here is that I do not know if there is a proper way to format each string and put them back together

```
//Code
import scala.util.Try
import scala.util.control.Breaks._
 val games =
      scala.collection.mutable.Map("Liz" -> "Game: 2324","John" -> "Game: 0 | Score: 9","Philip" -> "Game: 523423","Kevin" -> "Game: N/A", "Him"->"Not a person")
    // just sorting the map
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62353779/scala-how-do-you-sort-a-map-that-has-a-string-with-numbers-in-it
    val nums = "(\\d+)?(?:\\D+(\\d+))?".r.unanchored

    val infos = games.toList.sortBy{
      case (_,nums(a,b)) => (Try(a.toInt).toOption
        ,Try(b.toInt).toOption)}
    infos.foreach{i=>
      breakable{
        val e = i.toString.replace("(", "").replace(")", "")
        val r = e.split(",")
        if (r(1).contains("Not a person")) break
        val t = r(1).split("\\D")
        //if (t(1).contains("N/A")) break
        //if (t(1).contains("|"))
        t.foreach{i=>
          if (i==""){}
          else{
            println(i)
            val formatter = java.text.NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance
            val out = formatter.format(i.toInt)
            println(out)}
            // 0
            // 0
            // 9
            // 9
            // 2324
            // 2,324
            // 523423
           // 523,423

        }
      }
    }
```

What I want to output from the List

```
List((Kevin,Game: N/A), (Him,Not a person), (John,Game: 0 | Score: 9), (Liz,Game: 2,324), (Philip,Game: 523,423))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `StringContext` to format the number strings.

```
import scala.util.Try

val nums = "(\\d+)?(?:\\D+(\\d+))?".r.unanchored
val digits = "\\d+".r.unanchored

val games = Map("Liz" -> "Game: 2324"
               ,"John" -> "Game: 0 | Score: 9"
               ,"Philip" -> "Game: 523423"
               ,"Kevin" -> "Game: N/A"
               ,"Him" -> "Not a person")

val infos = games.toList.sortBy{
  case (_,nums(a,b)) => (Try(a.toInt).toOption
                        ,Try(b.toInt).toOption)
}.map { case (a,b) =>
  (a, digits.replaceAllIn(b, m => f"${m.matched.toInt}%,d"))
}
//infos: List[(String, String)] = List((Him,Not a person)
//                                  , (Kevin,Game: N/A)
//                                  , (John,Game: 0 | Score: 9)
//                                  , (Liz,Game: 2,324)
//                                  , (Philip,Game: 523,423))
```